# Conditional Averaging

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two numerical columns here(adm_muac1 and adm_muac2). I want create a third column which is an average of the two but on condition that both columns are non missing(I expect missing values in my data set), else it should not average but return either the non-missing columns as value for third column.

I wrote this code

```
df2<-mutate(df1,
   col3=ifelse((!is.na(col1)&!is.na(col2)),(col1+col2)/2,
                              col1|col2))
```

Here is the data set

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c(12,23,NA,14,15,20),col2=c(NA,20,16,17,18,NA))
Expectedcol3
12
27.5
16
15.5
16.5
20
```

The first part is excuting really well, but the second part is not. The idea is that I want the average if both col1 and col2 are non missing, else no averaging but I should get either of the non missing column between col1 and col2 as my entry col3.
Any help will  highly be appreciated

Thank you

```
col1    col2    col3
15.6    15.5    15.55
17      17.3    17.15
11.1              1
12.4    12.4    12.4
12.3    12.2    12.25
13      13.1    13.05
10.1    10.2    10.15
10.4    10.5    10.45
11      11.1     11.05
9.1     9.3    9.2
11.6    11.9    11.75
        11.4    1
11.2    11.4    11.3
11.2    11.1    11.15
10.2    10.3    10.25
12.1    12.2    12.15
15.9    15.8    15.85
15.1    15.1    15.1
9.5     9.8     9.65
11.4    11.4    11.4
11.7    11.6    11.65
         9.3      1
```

Comment: There will be type coercion as you have a mean and a logical one.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  How about just use `rowMeans(df1[c('col1', 'col2')], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Based on your description, I think `rowMeans` would be enough ( please check the updated comment above)

Comment: @akrun I am trying to share a sample data set and I am not able to coz I do not know how, I am new to the forum!

Comment: You can just click on the edit button.  suppose your dataset is `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(3, 4, NA, 2, NA), col2 = c(NA, 2, NA, 3, 2))` what would be the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could do a nested ifelse. If one is `NA`, choose the other, otherwise average them.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(col3 = ifelse(is.na(col1), col2, 
                             ifelse(is.na(col2), col1, (col1+col2)/2)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code worked magic and my problem has been solved.

Comment: Excellent, can you please upvote my answer and check the flag?

Comment: I did that but seems like I am too new to the forum to upvote, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can just do a `rowMeans`

```
df1$col3 <- rowMeans(df1[1:2], na.rm = TRUE)
```